# Making div visible does have some issue on mouseenter event

Tags: jquery, html

**Simple Terms**
I want `#livecart` be visible on `#cart` hover & keep it visible if I hover on `#livecart`. If I hover on any other div, it should be hidden.

It may be hard to explain.

**But here is the jsfiddle.**
http://jsfiddle.net/8fwFD/

First scenario: Go to the link, hover on Cart, then on any other & then again directly to Cart.
Second: Hover on Cart, then on any other, then any outside area & then to Cart.

In second scenario, it works fine. On first, it doesn't.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You are reconnecting `hover` events *every time you move out of the carttotal*!!!

Comment: Please have another go at explaining what the desired behaviour is, rather than describing the bug, as the code is never going to work properly as-is.

Comment: What do you mean by reconnecting hover event?

Comment: You are attaching `hover` events inside of another event... every time that event occurs (#carttotal mouseout) you are adding yet another hover handler to `#home` *and* `#livecart`.

Comment: @ShanilSoni You want to display the div upon hovering cart and hide it on mouse out… is that is, or am i missing something..? if so can you somehow explain the question in a bette manner (*in simple words - something like the first sentence of this comment instead of abc, scenarios etc*)..?

Comment: I want to display the div upon hovering cart & keep it active if I go to that div otherwise hide it. A simple thing.

Comment: @ShanilSoni since there is a huge gap in between the div an cart option, how do we know whether the user is planning to go to cart or somewhere else..?

Comment: Actually there is not a huge gap between #cart & #livecart, in jsfiddle, couldn't include everything. So there is not much gap.

Comment: @ShanilSoni even if it's a 1px gap, the div will be hidden when the mouse is out. the problem is either with the way you're trying to do the user interaction or the way you're explaining the expected behavior. From what i understood i've added an answer, you can comment below it for some modification of it's behavior...

Comment: In simple words, when user hovers on cart button, it displays cart preview through #livecart, now if user goes from cart button to any other div except #livecart, #livecart should be hidden. I can understand even 1px gap can hide the div, that is why I want surrounding all divs having mousehover event to hide #livecart, if you can understand what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i understood from the comments, you could try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#carttotal').on('mouseenter', function (e) {
    $("#livecart").css("display", "block"); 
  });
  $('#home, #myprofile').on('mouseenter', function () {
    $('#livecart').hide();
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8fwFD/3/)

This shows the div when cart is hovered and keeps it visible until user hovers over some other div...

Comment: Okay it's done, I added one more parent div to achieve what exactly what I wanted, thanks for helping out :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this jquery....

```
$("#carttotal").mouseenter(function () {
    $("#livecart").show();
});
$("#carttotal").mouseout(function () {
    $("#livecart").hide();
});
```

**Edit:**

Do you want this...

```
$("#carttotal").mouseenter(function () {
  if ($('#livecart').css('display') == 'none') 
     $("#livecart").show();
  else
     $("#livecart").hide();

    });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6bf9G/2/

Comment: There is a button labelled "TidyUp" in JSFiddle... Please use it :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie next time onwards  :)

Comment: Well, this is something I know. But I want #livecart being active if I leave #carttoal & enters #livecart itself. So in mouseout event is not something I should reply upon.

Comment: @Shanil Soni, plz look my edited answer..

Comment: No this is not what I want, please look at the last comment on above answer to get exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 $("#carttotal").mouseenter(function () {
        if ($('#livecart').css('display') == 'none') $("#livecart").show();
        else $("#livecart").hide();

    });
    $("#myprofile, #home").hover(function () {
        $("#livecart").hide();
    });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6bf9G/3/

Comment: @Shanil Soni plz check this, is this you expect..only to know :)